# Not all rows being returned

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what I'm missing. There should be 2 rows returned, yet only one of them is being returned.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status != 0"; # echo($query);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "liwp", "******", "liwp");
#$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query);
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* fetch object array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $cust_id        = $row[0];
    $customer_id    = $row[1];
    $first_name     = $row[2];
    $last_name      = $row[3];
    $address1       = $row[4];
    $address2       = $row[5];
        if ($address1 && $address2) { $br = "<br>"; } else { $br = ""; }
    $city           = $row[6];
    $zip            = $row[7];
    $email          = $row[8];
    $phone          = $row[9];
        if ($email && $phone) { $br2 = "<br>"; } else { $br2 = ""; }
    $status         = $row[10];

    $query2 = "SELECT status FROM statuses WHERE status_id = '$status'"; # echo($query2);

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "liwp", "******", "liwp");
        $result = $mysqli->query($query2);

$count = 0;
/* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) { $status_name = $row[0]; $count++; }
        if (!isset($status_name)) {
            $status_name = "";
            }
            echo "status - $status_name - $count";
        echo "<tr><td>$cust_id</td><td>$customer_id</td><td>$first_name $last_name</td><td>$address1$br$address2<br>$city CA $zip</td><td>$email$br2$phone</td><td>$status_name</td>";
        echo "<td>[del] [edit] [measures]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
```

I might just need a 2nd pair of eyes, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: 2 rows from which query?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The first query: $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status != 0"; # echo($query);

Comment: Remove the second connection and never do it again. Rename your second result variable. Rewrite your query to a single join

Comment: Lesson learned: don't re-use variable names for two different jobs